# How to query non keyword field in elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I want to filter records by non keyword field.

I am using aws elasticsearch service, where there are some fields are keyword and some are normal. I want to apply filtration on non keyword (text) data type field.

```
GET ES_INDEX_NAME/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "listing_group" : "Other"}
    }
}
```

listing_group field name is of text data type.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `match` or `match_phrase`?

For **partial** match,

```
GET ES_INDEX_NAME/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "listing_group" : "Other"
        }
    }
}
```

For **phrase** match,

```
GET ES_INDEX_NAME/_search
{     
    "query" : {      
        "match_phrase" : {      
            "listing_group" : "Other"      
        }      
    }      
}
```

Comment: This answer will probably solve your problem, but you can use a **term** query to query a text field. One difference between **term** and **match** (or **match_phrase**) is that **match** queries will apply analyzers. In your case, there is probably a lowercase analyzer in the `listing_group` field, so the **term** query will compare `"Other"` (in the query) and `"other"` (the value indexed) while using a **match** query `"Other"` will be transformed to `"other"` in the query. If you run a **term** query with `"other"` the document will be returned.

Comment: @Pierre-NicolasMougel, thank you. Very informative  +1

Comment: Worked !! thanks @Always Sunny and @ Pierre-Nicolas Mougel for such a informative answer.